# How to implement a time series sampler in MySQL system?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, triggers, time-series

I want to record the growth rate of values in columns of MySQL table.

What is the quickest way to implement a sub-program that automatically writes the values to another table at given-time intervals?
combination of stored procs / triggers / functions?

Comment: You can use a cronjob or you could even schedule an event from mysql http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a table that gets over 2 million detailed rows/day.

I have a trigger that writes summary data to another table.  I summarize the data into 5-minute "buckets" by converting the original datetime, yielding about 350K rows/day.

After a week, I have a cronjob that rolls the 5-minute buckets into hourly buckets, even further reducing storage to about 80K rows/day.

We use the summary data for reporting and also for longer storage.

It's a poor-man's RRD structure.

Hope that helps.